# Different tags for conditionals

Tags: discussion, status-completed, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

What's the difference between

- [if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statement)
- [conditional-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-statements) and
- [condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condition)?

I know the distinction between a statement and the [conditional-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-operator), but if that's the only difference, should the first two be merged?

The conditional-statements currently have a [tag wiki entry](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/conditional-statements/info) that matches [the condition one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/condition/info) quite literally, both were created by the Community user. Do they describe a special sort of conditional statements that are not if-elses (like `jmpzero`, `try-catch` or `switch` which might be used for [branching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science)))? If so, what should the tag wiki and excerpt read, and how many would need to be retagged?

Comment: Those look like useless tags to me.

Comment: @Stijn: You mean, burninating all of them? No, they're very valid for questions that ask about these statements/operators themselves or how to do branching correctly. Admittedly, they could need some cleanup.

Comment: I can only speak for myself of course, but I'd never search for these tags or subscribe to them. Then again there's a truckload of tags that I don't understand, perhaps I'm not fully grasping the point of the system.

Comment: Searching for the [if-statement] tag paired with [java] is a good way to find duplicates of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1288)