# I have a [conditional] [condition]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I noticed we have both [conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional) and [condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condition), which are perfect options for someone wanting to perform a [conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional) [condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condition) check.

Besides, [conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional) has a slightly hilarious tag wiki excerpt:

> Conditional has various meanings for various languages and probably should be avoided as a tag.

Laughs aside, are they something up for a merge?

---

Not a dupe: [Different tags for conditionals](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266784/5958455)

This one specifically talks about 2 tags, without involving [if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statement), and is looking for support/disagreement about merging them.

Comment: When suggesting retags, please include some discussion of how the tag is currently being used on questions, and what impact the retag would have. Would it be acceptable to just merge them? Or do they need to be manually disambiguated? In other words, retag requests shouldn't just focus on the abstract definition of the tags themselves, but also provide a practical assessment.

Comment: @CodyGray So... you're saying the merge has conditions?

Comment: Conditionally yes @Machavity.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the condition of those questions as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather like to merge all these tags together with [conditional-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-statements) as the master. The tags:

- [condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condition)
- [conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditionals)
- [conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditions)
- [conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional)

etc are not quite specific, whereas a conditional statement is a specific concept in programming. The fact that the synonym [conditional-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-statements) which had  1247 at the time of creation, was renamed 1634 to [conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional) supports this argument as well.

Doing this would be a bit tricky as we can't have synonym chains. Anyway this is the current scenario

- [condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/condition) ← [conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditions)
- [conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional) ← [conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditionals)
- [conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional) ← [conditional-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-statements)

Anyway, I just broke all these synonyms and added them all as a synonym for [conditional-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/conditional-statements).